# Run a batch file as admin in a different server

Tags: c#, batch-file, server, admin, runas

I am trying to run a batch file using my C# script which is placed on a different server. **My C# script is on one production server X** and the **batch file is on another production server Y.**

My C# script is placed on the task scheduler using a service account which I have added to the server Y as well as an admin and I have given the security rights to the batch file.

Is there anything I might be missing in my code below:

```
private static void runE(string file)//function to run the E as admin
    {
        Process proc = null;
        try
        {
            string batDir = string.Format(@"\\ServerY_IP\d$\E\D\");
            proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = batDir;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = file;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.Verb = @"runas";
            proc.StartInfo.Domain = "ServerY_IP";
            proc.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
            proc.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(file + " is being executed");
            WriteLog(file + " is being executed");
            proc.WaitForExit(); //wait forever
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
            Console.WriteLine(file + " file completed.");
            WriteLog(file + " file completed.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLog("Process finished with Errors" + ex.Message);
        }
     }
```

I am passing the "kick.bat" file as argument value to this. This file is the one I need to run as admin. 
To troubleshoot this I also created another batch file in the same folder and it runs but this "kick.bat" doesn't run.

I found the probable issue with it by running it in the test. After running the task in the test, I received the window pop up prompting me to say yes or no to run the file as admin. How do I embed the yes for the prompt in my C# script?

Comment: Is it throwing any exceptions or any other errors, or is it just not running?

Comment: @TJWolschon The question is very specific and it states that _..."but this "kick.bat" doesn't run."_

Comment: No, it is not giving any errors in the case of that kick.bat file.